# Save users list in main loop [Discord bot]

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py, bots

You need to call the function to save the list of users at a certain time.
For example:

```
def save(array):
    with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(array, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

But the problem is that I don't understand how it can be shoved into the main loop of the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a task which periodically repeats your function

---

```
import asyncio

def save(array):
    while(True): # repeat endlessly
        with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
            json.dump(array, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
        await asyncio.sleep(1000) # wait 1000 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # do your on_ready routine
    array = [] # whatever you need to write in there
    client.loop.create_task(save(array))
```